# Changing the font size of figure captions in RMarkdown HTML output

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I would like to make the font size of all figure captions in my R Markdown document smaller. The final output is HTML and I'm working in R Studio. To load the picture, I use the `include_graphics` function from `knitr`, because I've been told it's the best way (see [here](http://www.zevross.com/blog/2017/06/19/tips-and-tricks-for-working-with-images-and-figures-in-r-markdown-documents/#default-settings-for-including-images-and-figures-in-r-markdown)). My .Rmd file is:

````
---
title: "ppp"
author: "ppp"
date: "July 4, 2017"
output: 
  html_document: 
    fig_caption: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```


```{r foo, fig.cap="$f_{p}$ as a function of $g$ for various values of $r=\\frac{\\rho_{w}}{\\rho_{a}}$"}
# All defaults
include_graphics("download.jpg")
``` 

This is regular text.
````

The corresponding output is:
[image]

As you can see, the caption font size and the regular text font size are *exactly* the same, which doesn't look that nice. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just add the following CSS to your Rmd document (anywhere below the YAML header):

```
<style>
p.caption {
  font-size: 0.6em;
}
</style>
```

**What are we doing here:**

If you mark the caption in your browser and inspect that element (Chrome: right-click -> Inspect) you can see that the caption is actually a HTML paragraph with a class named `caption`:

```
<p class="caption"> ... </p>
```

With the above CSS code we change the font-size of exactly those elements (and only those) to 60% of the default size.

---

[image]

Comment: Would +2 your answer for the Doge meme  just a question, where do I put this CSS in my Rmd doc? In the YAML header?

Comment: No, you put it somewhere below the YAML. I prefer to put CSS or JavaScript Code right below the YAML.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot :) ps I had a look at your GitHub and learned this nifty trick: instead than `date: "July 4, 2017"`, `date:  "\`r Sys.Date()\`"` is much better!

Comment: If you use Bookdown or Blogdown, you can add the same CSS to your main CSS file. (without the <style>)

Answer (score 0):

To embed it within the RMD documents, use this [chunk](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html):

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
p {
  font-size: 32px;
}
```
````

How this looks within the whole RMD file:

````
---
title: "ppp"
author: "ppp"
date: "July 4, 2017"
output: 
  html_document: 
    fig_caption: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```


```{css, echo=FALSE}
p {
  font-size: 32px;
}
```


```{r foo, fig.cap="$f_{p}$ as a function of $g$ for various values of $r=\\frac{\\rho_{w}}{\\rho_{a}}$"}
# All defaults
include_graphics("download.jpg")
```
````

This is regular text.