# Changing the font size of figure captions in RMarkdown Word output

Tags: r, ms-word, knitr, r-markdown

I recently asked

[Changing the font size of figure captions in RMarkdown HTML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45018397/changing-the-font-size-of-figure-captions-in-rmarkdown-html-output)

and I got [a very nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45022100/1711271) which uses this CSS method. I wanted to try the same, but this time with Word output. If you don't want to read my former question, I summarize the issue here: I'd like to make the font size of all figure captions in my R Markdown document smaller. The final output is Word,this time, and I'm working in R Studio. To load the picture, I use the `include_graphics` function from `knitr`, because I've been told it's the best way (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45022100/1711271)). My .Rmd file is:

````
---
title: "ppp"
author: "ppp"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  word_document: 
    fig_caption: yes
  html_document: 
    fig_caption: yes
---

<style>
p.caption {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
</style>


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```


```{r foo, fig.cap="$f_{p}$ as a function of $g$ for various values of $r=\\frac{\\rho_{w}}{\\rho_{a}}$"}
# All defaults
include_graphics("download.jpg")
```

This is regular text.
````

The corresponding output is:

[image]

Clearly, this CSS method doesn't work (I guess it's something related to HTML, so it doesn't render in Word). In Word I can manually change the font size for each caption, but I'd rather set some global R Markdown parameter. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Almost as easy as in the HTML case. The following applies to the workflow using LibreOffice. But in Word it should be almost the same:*

1. Produce your docx output file.
2. Open it in LibreOffice (or Word, or Pages, ...)
3. In LibreOffice, right-click the caption and choose *Edit Style* (in Word you can open the styles pane with *Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S*)

[image]

4. In the menu that popped up you can modify the style for *Image Captions*

[image]

5. When you are done editing the style, click *Apply* and just save the file as a docx called *template.docx*

Finally, add a style reference in the YAML header of your Rmd document like

```
title: "ppp"
author: "ppp"
date: "July 4, 2017"
output: 
  word_document:
    reference_docx: template.docx
    fig_caption: yes
```

And the captions should be smaller now according to how you changed the style in your reference document.

Comment: You know *everything*! Can you point me to a resource to learn all these R Markdown tricks?

Comment: Google and Stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Ouch ;) was hoping for a nice, detailed tutorial with slides or videos somewhere... thanks anyway :)