# Changing the font size of figure captions in RMarkdown PowerPoint output

Tags: r, r-markdown, powerpoint, knitr, officer

I'm attempting to adjust the font size of figure captions rendered below a map/chart in PowerPoint (PPT).

The examples below have been produced using chunk options such as `r world_map, fig.cap="[A LINK](./PATH/TO/*.html)"` and `r car_chart, fig.cap="[ANOTHER LINK](./PATH/TO/*.html)"` respectively.

#### Slide with map and caption

```
library(tmap)

data("World")

m <- tm_shape(World, group = "World") +
        tm_borders()
m
```

[image: slide with map and caption]

#### Slide with chart and caption

```
library(ggplot2)

data("cars")

p <- ggplot(cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
    geom_point()
p
```

[image: slide with chart and caption]

Solutions have been provided by @MartinSchmelzer for [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45018397/changing-the-font-size-of-figure-captions-in-rmarkdown-html-output) and [Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45032180/changing-the-font-size-of-figure-captions-in-rmarkdown-word-output) outputs, namely `CSS` syntax and edits to the Word template.
The `CSS` approach is not supported for PPT outputs, and editing the PPT template (`*.potx`) is not an option either because, unlike Word, PPT does not explicitly support figure captions. The [figure caption in PowerPoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/insert-a-caption-for-a-picture-bb74994c-7f8b-457c-be85-92233177a356) is simply a text box placed next to a figure and grouped with it.

Given this, I looked for alternative solutions in the `OfficeR` package by @DavidGohel. The [example](https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/officer-for-powerpoint.html#ggplot-objects) provided in the documentation uses a simple `print` command to add text below a chart. In PPT, this would render in the next slide, not below the chart.
This [OfficeR tutorial](http://lenkiefer.com/2017/09/23/crafting-a-powerpoint-presentation-with-r/) refers to "Picture with Caption" as a two columns slide (alike the PPT template), not as a text rendered below the map/chart.

As yet, neither I found a solution to format `fig.cap` in PPT, nor I found another option to render a string of text below an chart/map in PPT. Does anyone know hoe to address this?

Comment: figure caption is not a real concept with powerpoint, you can use https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/officer-for-powerpoint.html#single-paragraph

Comment: Hi @DavidGohel! Yes, I figured that PPT doesn't have such a feature. Would you be able to provide a workable example to add and format a string of text *below* a chart/image using `officeR`, `officeverse`, `officedown` or any other of yours? That would be very much appreciated!

Comment: The link I provided contains an example of formatted string. You have to choose a location that fit your need on the slide with ph_location_type or another ph_location as demo here: https://ardata-fr.github.io/officeverse/officer-for-powerpoint.html#content-location