# Changing the font size of figure captions in RMarkdown pdf output

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I would like to make the font size of all captions (figures and tables) in my R Markdown document smaller. I'm using bookdown. The final output is pdf and I'm working in R Studio. To load the picture, I use the `include_graphics` function from `knitr`, because I've been told it's the best way (see [here](http://www.zevross.com/blog/2017/06/19/tips-and-tricks-for-working-with-images-and-figures-in-r-markdown-documents/#default-settings-for-including-images-and-figures-in-r-markdown)).

I only found the exact same question, but for html output [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45018397/changing-the-font-size-of-figure-captions-in-rmarkdown-html-output/45022100#45022100)

An example `.rmd`:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

Normal text has the same size as the captions.

```{r, echo = FALSE, out.width = '50%', fig.cap = "The caption has the same size as normal text."}
knitr::include_graphics('logo.png')
```
````

[image]

As you can see, the caption font size and the regular text font size are *exactly* the same, which doesn't look that nice. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's acceptable using LaTeX packages, you can use `caption`

````
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{caption}
   - \captionsetup[figure]{font=scriptsize}
---

Normal text has the same size as the captions.

```{r, echo = FALSE, out.width = '50%', fig.cap = "The caption has the same size as normal text."}
knitr::include_graphics('logo.png')

```
````

Replace `scriptsize` to change size. You can find a list of default LaTeX font sizes here:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts#Built-in_sizes

The `caption` package on CTAN:

https://ctan.org/pkg/caption