# Change font and color for figure captions in Rmarkdown in PDF output

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm wondering how to change font and color specifically for figure captions in Rmarkdown for a PDF output. I know how to do this for word output (creating a separate document), but often figures are submitted to journals as PDFs.

Note that this is not whether you can change the color of text in a PDF which is answered here: [Changing the font size of figure captions in RMarkdown pdf output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56271711/changing-the-font-size-of-figure-captions-in-rmarkdown-pdf-output). If I try this within the `fig.cap = "fig text here.\\label{...}"` I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \cellcolor
```

This probably comes closest: [Changing the font size of figure captions in RMarkdown pdf output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56271711/changing-the-font-size-of-figure-captions-in-rmarkdown-pdf-output), but I went to CTAN and downloaded the package and am not sure whether I have to find my R libraries and drag it to there, or what. Perhaps this is the only/easiest solution, if so, can you advise on how I should proceed with the downloaded package. Haven't done a lot in latex, so it would probably be finding how colors are defined in latex as well?

Thanks much!

James

Here is my header:

```
output:
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: true
  html_document: default
header-includes:
  \usepackage{placeins}

---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "bttomio"
date: "6/13/2021"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="\\textcolor{red}{This is red} and \\textcolor{blue}{this is blue}"}
plot(pressure)
```
````

-output

[image]

Comment: Ah--that's great! How about changing font?

Comment: Nice, glad to help. Could you please check [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_sizes,_families,_and_styles)?

Comment: Thanks so much for this! The link is helpful.

Comment: @bttmio for some reason, this doesn't work for `format: pptx`. Do you know of a way for a powerpoint output in `qmd`?