# Changing the caption font size, color, and style in PPTX qmd

Tags: r, powerpoint, quarto

How do I, correctly, change the format of a plot caption in a `qmd` file? With a `pptx` output.

I'll provide my MWE:

````
---
title: "My Work"
subtitle: "2023"
author: "Me"
format: pptx
reference-doc: template.pptx
mainfont: Open Sans
sansfont: Open Sans
slide-level: 1
---

# Slide 1
```{r, fig.align = "center", fig.cap="Caption"}
    # code for the graph
```
````

The only command that I found that can help me modify it, is obviously, the `fig.caption`. But besides that, I have no control over the way the caption is presented, in terms of style, and I would like to know other alternatives.

With simply `fig.caption = "Caption"`I get something like this:

[image: slide1]

When what I was looking for, is the following:

[image: slide2]

In case the changes aren't obvious, the part *"Figure 1"* has a style **bold**, with a darkblue color, and the rest *"Overlaying Graphs"* has a normal lettering style, and the color is lightgray.

Can anyone help?

Comment: [This link to change color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67954372/change-font-and-color-for-figure-captions-in-rmarkdown-in-pdf-output) and [This link to change font](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_sizes%2C_families%2C_and_styles)

Comment: I've viewed those links before. Didn't work, everything remained the same.

Comment: The suggested links in the previous comment is for `format: pdf` but the question here is about `format: beamer`.  So the answers in those suggested links will not work in this case.

Comment: @shafee exactly. More precisely, for `format: pptx` (if there is no diference in terms of the code used in `format: beamer` and `format: pptx`, please correct me).

Comment: oopss, sorry! I have said `format: beamer` mistakenly, I should have said `format: pptx` and yes they are different.

Comment: I have a related issue. Figures in quarto/pandoc rendered powerpoints slide decks can have captions. These captions appear to be rendered at 18 pt but don't seem to correspond to any master slide attributes in my specified reference-doc.